# Returning two objects with move semantics

Tags: c++

I need to return two class objects from a function and I saw some code doing the following:

```
class ReturnObject {
public:
ReturnObject(std::vector<int>&& a1, std::map<int, int>&& a2) :
  o1(std::forward<std::vector<int>>(a1)),
    o2(std::forward< std::map<int, int>>(a2)) 
  {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    ReturnObject(ReturnObject&& other) :
     o1(std::move(other.o1)),
     o2(std::move(other.o2)) 
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<int> o1;
    std::map<int, int> o2;
};

ReturnObject function() {
    std::vector<int> o1;
    std::map<int, int> o2;

    return {std::move(o1), std::move(o2)};
}

int main()
{
    ReturnObject destination = function();
}
```

my question is: is this a good way to return two objects or is this code  unnecessarily complex?

AFAIK this should move-optimize the two objects and trigger RVO.

Comment: `std::pair` will do what you want

Comment: If you have more than two returns then you can use a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to return an aggregate:

```
struct ReturnObject {
    std::vector<int> o1;
    std::map<int, int> o2;
};

ReturnObject function() {
    ReturnObject ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Or you could return a pair or tuple, rather than defining your own type, if you don't mind losing the member names.

Comment: What would be the difference for an aggregate and a pair? If I return an aggregate by value, will that trigger the move constructors for every aggregate member? (I think this is valid for pair)

Comment: @Albert: Yes, both an aggregate and a pair/tuple would move each member (and both would be subject to RVO). The difference is largely aesthetic.

Comment: Oh I forgot an important question: will it make any difference in the aggregate case if I  used `return {o1, o2};` or `return {std::move(o1), std::move(o2)};` ? Clang seems to accept both and I'm not sure why

Comment: @Albert: I think the first would copy them to initialise the object; but I'd need to check to be sure. If you make the object a local variable as in my example, rather than a temporary, then there definitely won't be any copying.

Comment: I think you're right: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/688efff58cbdbbe8 this might potentially be expensive, better keep the std::move in the aggregate initialization

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `std::pair<T1, T2>`? See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair